# How to change Matplotlib from version2 to version 3?

Tags: matplotlib

When I type `matploblib.__version__` in python, it returns `'2.1.2'`. I am wondering is there a way to change matplotlib 2 to matplotlib 3?

I am using python3 and MacOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the latest version via conda or pip:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib==3.1.3
or 
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

Check out the tutorial on this page.
https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html